# showsUserLocation returns pin instead of blue dot in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

This is my `-mapView:viewForAnnotation` method which drops pins when i create annotation views. But when i set `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;` in `-viewDidLoad`, i get a pin dropped on Infinite Loop (expected - in simulator) and not the normal blue dot.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
     MKAnnotationView *anno = nil;
     //create a pin annotation view
MKPinAnnotationView  *pin=[[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"]autorelease];

    [pin setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorRed];
    pin.animatesDrop=YES;
    pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    pin.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    anno = pin;
    return anno;
}
```

How can i get it to drop pins and show the blue dot as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Really simple to fix, although unsure if this is the correct way to do it...

```
if (annotation == mapView.userLocation){
    return nil; //default to blue dot
}
```

Comment: And you have to wonder *why* is this the correct way to it and yet we can't `setUserLocation` ....

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer, here's something close:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    NSString *annotationType = [NSString stringWithCString:object_getClassName(annotation)];
    if ([annotationType compare:@"NSKVONotifying_MKUserLocation"] == 0)
        return nil;
    ...
}
```

Of course, use something like this at your own risk.  It could stop working tomorrow if Apple decided to change that name.

Answer (score 0):

Often you use your own class of annotation to look up information related to the annotation. In that case, to only handle your own annotations, use something like

```
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapLocation class]]) {}
```